# tensorflow: two initializers ops found for one convlayer

Tags: python, tensorflow

when i read my model operations with

```
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node
```

if find multiple initializer ops for the same weight layer:

```
'model/conv2d/kernel/Initializer/truncated_normal/TruncatedNormal'
'model/conv2d/kernel/Initializer/truncated_normal'
```

when i read back the tensors with

```
tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('model/conv2d/kernel/Initializer/truncated_normal/TruncatedNormal:0')
```

, they have the same shape/dimension but other values.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Are you also reading another tensor?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "reading another tensor"? The conv2d layer of this model exists only once, exactly with this name. So in my opinion there should only be one initialization process and only one tensor with this name, am i right?!

Comment: That doesn't mean you have two initializers for the same layer, it's just different operations that are part of the initializer. You can check the type, inputs and outputs of the operations to see what each of them does exactly, but it is normal to have a "higher-level" operation (in this case an initializer) composed of other smaller operations under inner namespaces.